# Does gorm.Open() create a new connection pool every time it's called?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I'm working on a piece of code that is making calls to the database from several different places.  In this code I have been using the GORM library, and calling `gorm.Open()` every time I need to interact with the database.

What I'm wondering is what is happening under the hood when I call this?  Is a new connection pool created every time I call it or is each call to `gorm.Open()` sharing the same connection pool?

Comment: It creates a new connection pool every time when you call `gorm.Open()` with default configuration. The recommendation is to use a single `*gorm.DB` in your application by either keeping it in a global variable or create a singleton  pattern for it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**TLDR:** yes, try to reuse the returned DB object.

[gorm.Open](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/v1.9.12/main.go#L58) does the following: (more or less):

1. lookup the driver for the given dialect
2. call `sql.Open` to return a `DB` object
3. call `DB.Ping()` to force it to talk to the database

This means that one `sql.DB` object is created for every `gorm.Open`. Per the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB), this means one connection pool for each DB object.

This means that the recommendations for [sql.Open](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open) apply to `gorm.Open`:

> The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and
>   maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function
>   should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, also note that the connection pool can be configured as such, in both GORM v1 and v2:

```golang
// SetMaxIdleConns sets the maximum number of connections in the idle connection pool.
db.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(10)

// SetMaxOpenConns sets the maximum number of open connections to the database.
db.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(100)

// SetConnMaxLifetime sets the maximum amount of time a connection may be reused.
db.DB().SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)
```

Calling the `DB()` function on the `*gorm.DB` instance returns the underlying `*sql.DB` instance.

Answer (score 7):

For those who are just starting with **gorm**, here is a more complete example.

```
db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(url))
if err != nil {
    // control error
}

sqlDB, err := db.DB()
if err != nil {
    // control error
}

sqlDB.SetMaxIdleConns(10)
sqlDB.SetMaxOpenConns(100)
sqlDB.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)
```